# Problema validando img_perfil de la tabla users (me valida la imagen aún sin seleccionar ninguna)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy personalizando los **templates y controladores** que te  crea automaticamente laravel con el comando :

> php artisan make:auth

Y pues bien, ya lo tengo casi terminado en una primera version de lo que yo quiero. Pero me he topado con el siguiente problema:

Le he añadido a la tabla `users` que crea por defecto laravel varios campos, para personalizarla, entre ellos el campo `img_perfil`. El tema de las **migraciones** y el **añadido de nuevos campos a la tabla users** no me han causado ningun tipo de problemas.

Pero el tema del campo `img_perfil` si que me pone impedimentos:


A la hora de **validarlo** en la parte **frontend** esta puesto con un `input` de tipo `file`:

```
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="img_perfil" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Imagen de perfil</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="img_perfil" type="file" class="form-control @error('img_perfil') is-invalid @enderror" name="img_perfil" value="{{ old('img_perfil') }}" autocomplete="img_perfil">
                        @error('img_perfil')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
```

En mi **validacion backend** (*fichero `Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php`*) lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],

            'apel_1'=>['string','max:255'],
            'apel_2'=>['string','max:255'],
            'user_name'=>['string','required','max:20','unique:users'],
            'img_perfil'=>['max:100000','mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif'],


        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

            'apel_1' => $data['apel_1'],
            'apel_2' => $data['apel_2'],
            'user_name' => $data['user_name'],
            'img_perfil' => $data['img_perfil']

        ]);
    }
}
```

Como se puede observar, en la validacion del campo `img_perfil` esta puesto de la siguiente manera: 
`'img_perfil'=>['max:100000','mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif'],`

Se entiende que la valdiacion que le hago es : *tamaño imagen|extensiones permitidas* no le estoy indicando que sea required, pues cuando hago una prueba de insertar usuario **sin seleccionar ninguna foto** me dice :

> The img perfil must be a file of type: jpg, png, jpeg, gif.

Pero eso me lo deberia de decir si he seleccionado una foto. Si no hay pues que no valide nada.

Comment: Agregarle `nullable` a la validación si quieres que no considere las valores null como no validos. Agregarle `sometimes` si no quieres que lo marque como inválido cuando no esté presente

Comment: era lo del `someitmes` gracias :)

Comment: Pudieras postear la migracion de la tabla Users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependiendo de como estés enviando el formulario, puedes usar:

```
'img_perfil'=>['nullable|max:100000|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif'],
```

si el campo va a estar siempre presente, aunque tenga `null` como valor.

O puedes usar:

```
'img_perfil'=>['sometimes|max:100000|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif'],
```

si el campo sólo va a estar presente cuando tenga un valor.

[`nullable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-nullable):
no considera los valores `null` como no validos.

[`sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#conditionally-adding-rules):
ejecuta verificaciones de validación en un campo solo si ese campo está presente.